# How to increase columns width in a gtsummary table in RMarkdown HTML file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, gtsummary

I'm working with gtsummary to create tables in RMarkdown HTML files. This is the code I'm using:

```
theme_gtsummary_language(
  language = "pt",
  decimal.mark = ",",
  big.mark = ".")

tab <- dados %>%
  select(anoobito, DESCRICAO.y) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = anoobito,
              label = c(DESCRICAO.y ~ "Causa Final")) %>%
  add_overall(last = T) %>%
  modify_table_body(fun = ~ dplyr::arrange(.x, desc(readr::parse_number(stat_0)))) %>%
  modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1":"stat_5") ~ "**Ano do Óbito**") %>%
  modify_header(label = "**Causa Final**",
                all_stat_cols() ~  "**{level}**<br>N = {n}") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  remove_row_type(type = "header") %>%
  modify_column_hide(columns = "stat_0")

tab$table_body <- head(tab$table_body, 10)

tab
```

I get the following result:

[image]

I was wondering if it's possible to increase columns width so "N =" appear under the years in a single row, just like the 2023 column.

Comment: @TarJae stefan's answer solved my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to convert to a `gt_tbl` object using `as_gt` which allows to set the column width using `gt::cols_width`:

- Default

```
library(gtsummary)

tab
```

[image]

- using `gt::cols_width` to increase the column width where I target the `stat_x` columns of the `gtsummaty` table using `starts_with`:

```
library(gt)

tab |> 
  as_gt() |> 
  gt::cols_width(starts_with("stat") ~ px(100))
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(123)

dados <- data.frame(
  DESCRICAO.y = c(
    "arcu vitae potenti interdum imperdiet vestibulum suscipit fringilla nascetur tristique",
    "morbi nostra at curae purus venenatis sed nascetur scelerisque blandit"
  ),
  anoobito = sample(2019:2023, 5000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.2, .3, .1, .2, .2))
)
```